# Problem with form_key after upgrade

Tags: cart, upgrade, enterprise-1.13

We just upgraded from 1.12 to 1.13.0.2 and in the UAT we found that the original theme did not have the form_key tag on the products. We added this to the add to cart URL and it worked.

Since then the client has added configurable products and although we have added the form_key tag to the add to cart URL the product still does not end up in the cart?

[image]

Comment: All the simple products have a form key and they work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was a little pre-mature in posting the question: But here is the solution!

Addtocart.phtml and view_configurable.phtml

[image]